# pytest testing internal functions

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say that I have a package `qaz`:

```
qaz/
   __init__.py
   qaz.py
tests/
   test_qaz.py
setup.py
```

Now, I want to test some internal `qaz.py` functions:

```py
def _abc():
    return 3

def def():
   return _abc() + 2
```

but when I run `pytest` with tests like this:

```py
from qaz.qaz import *

def test_abc():
    assert _abc() == 3

def test_def():
    assert def() == 5
```

My question is how to test `_abc()`?

Now I'm getting:

```
E       NameError: name '_abc' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, figured it out. You need to be specific, when it comes to the internal functions:

```py
from qaz.qaz import _abc
```

Comment: This is documented behavior, described in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement. `from foo import *` isn't really recommended, though.